# refactoring function with different methods - javascript

Tags: javascript

This function current takes in an array, and outputs it a character with its count if the element's length is greater than one

Is there a way I can do this same thing, perhaps with a different javascript array method without having to use a new array or a result variable?

```js
const a = ['aaa', 'z', 'eeeee'];

const compressCharacters = arr => {
  let newArray = [];

  let result = arr.forEach(e => e.length > 1 ? newArray.push(`${e[0]}${e.length}`) : newArray.push(e))

  return newArray.join("");
}

console.log(compressCharacters(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `map()` instead of `forEach()` and return the values you want. There's no need for the extra array. It's often the case than `forEach + push()` == `map()`

```js
const a = ['aaa', 'z', 'eeeee'];

const compressCharacters = arr => {
  return arr.map(e => e.length > 1
           ? `${e[0]}${e.length}` 
           : e)
           .join("");
}

console.log(compressCharacters(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct and immediately return a `map`ped array, that's joined by the empty string:

```js
const a = ['aaa', 'z', 'eeeee'];
const compressCharacters = arr => (
  arr.map(str => str[0] + (str.length > 1 ? str.length : ''))
    .join('')
)

console.log(compressCharacters(a));
```

When you're trying to construct a new array by transforming all elements from some other array, `.map` is the appropriate method to use. `forEach` should be reserved for generic iteration with side effects, when you aren't trying to construct a new object. (when you *are* trying to construct a new object, but it's not an array, or the new array isn't one-to-one with the old array, usually you can use `.reduce`)

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative using the function `reduce` to build the desired output.

```js
const a = ['aaa', 'z', 'eeeee'],
      result = a.reduce((a, [m], i, arr) => {
        let {length} = arr[i];
        return a + m + (length <= 1 ? "" : length);
      }, "");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you explain how this works? I've never used an array in the reduce method before or deconstructed the length of an array like that before